# Point cloud vertical profiles and measurements (QGIS version 3.22)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using QGIS version 3.22.3 (QGIS 3.18+ supports point cloud visualisation natively, see [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog318/)). I have some point cloud data generated from LiDAR instruments. I would like to generate several vertical profiles at various locations of the point cloud extents. And I would like to make vertical measurements, to determine vertical height differences.

For example, in ArcMAP 10.5, after I have loaded the LiDAR data, I can use the “profile view” tool. In that tool, I can make vertical measurements. Please see the screenshot below; blue points are from one point cloud source and red one are from another. Is there any way to do the same thing in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update august 2022:**

Since version 3.26 of QGIS, it is possible to produce elevation profiles. To do this you need to activate the *elevation profile* panel via the *view* menu. You can then create a profile using the *capture curve* tool.

[image: Utilisation of profile tool in QGis]

**Initial answer:**

For the moment, only the visualization of point clouds is possible in QGIS. Advanced tools, including profiles, are under development ([there was recently a new funding campaign](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/crowdfunding/elevation-pointcloud-enhancements-qgis/)). This will be for a future version of QGIS.

You can do this with two libre softwares :

- [CloudCompare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/)
- [pdal](https://pdal.io/apps/translate.html#example-1) (if you need a script)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do this using open source software? Note that it needs to handle shapefiles too. If so, please edit your answer to mention them.

Comment: Yes. You can see the edit

Comment: Thanks so much for that!